# De onde vem esta "tooltip" de notificação

Tags: html

Estava fazendo um desenvolvimento de uma pagina ASPX com JQUERY, W3DATA e w3CSS, e quando fiz um submit do meu formulário, o seguinte popup apareceu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os campos do formulário contem a chave "required", porem não especifiquei em nenhum lugar para iniciar a validação.

De onde vem esta notificação? É possível controlar? Se sim, como?

Comment: Creio eu que seja de cada navegador, isso vem do HTML5, cada navegador tem o seu estilo, posso estar errado.

Comment: Se você não quer que apareça é só remover o required.

Answer (score 3):

Tem certeza de que não especificou? [Esse recurso é parte do HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

O campo em tela deve estar assim:

```
<input type="text" name="titulo_notificacao" required>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa especificar em nenhum lugar para o HTML5 validar o formulário. Contendo o `required` e um botão de submit no form, essa mensagem aparecerá.

Caso o input for `type="email"`por exemplo, ele vai pedir para que coloque o e-mail no formato certo, com o @. Qualquer input que tiver um `pattern`, ele vai mostrar a mensagem pedindo que o input seja digitado no formato correto.

> Lembrando que essa mensagem só aparece no chrome, no firefox não aparece (mas continua validando).

Answer (score -1):

Esse tooltrip é um atributo do html required. Certamente sua propriedade está com essa anotação. Ou essa propriedade está declarada no html.

Exemplo:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha este campo")]
public string Notificacao{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Não lembro se apenas isso anota `required` na tag do campo. Era bom fazer um teste.

Comment: Sim, ele o torna required, porém na sua view você tem que adicionar o ValidationMessageFor do Razor.

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notificacao)

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e fica assim: `<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="Preencha este campo" data-val-required="Preencha este campo" id="Preco" name="Preco" type="text" value="">`. Não é a mesma coisa.